# How to block php extension while still route many php endpoint in nginx

Tags: nginx

For many reasons we don't want/need to have user access php directly. Actually our php backend **mostly** serve Restful API. Only small portion of the code serve some MVC web. It is like describe below

1. *mywebsite.com/abcsomething.php*         -> block it ( harder to hack ?! )
2. *mywebsite.com/api/abc?xyz*              ->  api.php (our API main point here)
3. *mywebsite.com/utility/abc?xyz*          ->  utility.php (good old php code)
4. *mywebsite.com/admin/abc?xyz*          ->  admin/admin.php (good old php code)
5. *mywebsite.com/everthing_else/something?xyz*          ->  generated/index.html ( everthing else is served as single page website )

We don't really have index.php but many php main describe above.

I have googled and tried for almost 4 days but could not get it done. What I got so far:

```
 ...
 root /www/app;

 ...
 location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
 }


 location ^~ /api {

 }

 location ^~ /utility {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  api.php;

        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
 }

 location ^~ /admin {
        root /www/app/admin
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  api.php;

        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
 }



 location / {
    root /www/app/generated
    try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

 ...
```

#1 and #5 seems to works but #2-4 I tried many techniques from try_files to rewrite, alias. But since I am inexperience, I could manage to get it works. Could someone give me a hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that any resource files are not relative to the same path, your approach is fine except for a couple of issues.

The `SCRIPT_FILENAME` needs to point to the script file to be executed (e.g. utility.php). The value for `$fastcgi_script_name` is inappropriate in this case, as it will be derived from the URI.

Also, `fastcgi_param` statements should be placed **after** `include fastcgi_params;` as the latter may contain conflicting statements.

For example:

```
location ^~ /api {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/api.php;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ^~ /utility {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/utility.php;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ^~ /admin {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/admin.php;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Obviously you could continue to construct the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` using the `$document_root` variable as a prefix, but that seems pointless to me for a hard-wired value.

The `REQUEST_METHOD` should be defined in the `fastcgi_params` file.

EDIT:

> BTW, I want to do something like remove the "api" prefix and send to
>   php. Like "/api/customer/1" -> will send "customer/1" only to php.

You will need to identify which parameter your script uses to read the URI, but it will be one of the variables listed in the `fastcgi_params` file (e.g. `REQUEST_URI`).

You could change the `location` statement to a regular expression and capture the part of the URI you are interested in, for example:

```
location ~ ^/api(?<name>.*)$ {
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/api.php;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI     $name$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Be sure to place the block above any conflicting regular expression blocks, as regular expression `location` blocks are evaluated in order.

Comment: wow, did not know that I was so close. But your answer does make things make more clear to me. Thanks, I will accept your answer. BTW, I want to do something like remove the "api" prefix and send to php. Like "/api/customer/1" -> will send "customer/1" only to php. I know it is weird but soon we will move the api somewhere else where the api will be removed/replaced. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: thanks for the update. I works like a charm! No more question needed